# Step-wise model selection on community dataset and predictor variables in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a dataset which has a community composition (site x species) matrix along with measurements of different environmental variables at the different sites, with the variables and species comprising the different columns.

I want to perform a stepwise model selection in R on this dataset to select predictor variables for the community composition data

I was hoping to use the stepAIC function, but am not sure how to fit the community matrix into lm. My code is -

```
pc <- read.csv("db_tele.csv", header = T) #full dataset
com <- pc[,15:ncol(pc)] #community composition data within dataset
var <- pc[,4:14] #environmental data (predictor variables) within dataset

dist <- vegdist(com, method = "jaccard") #community matrix based on jaccard similarity

full.model <- lm(dist ~ var, data = pc) #attempting to fit these data into lm to use with stepAIC, this is where the code fails

stepAIC(full.model, scale = 0, direction = "both", trace = FALSE)
```

Comment: It appears that vegdist returns a distance matrix. What is your response variable? 
What kind of error do you see?

Comment: Perhaps you need to create another distance matrix of `var` so that you are predicting community distance from environmental distance. But then you only have one predictor so stepwise would not make sense.

Comment: @RicVillalba the error is `Error in model.frame.default(formula = dist ~ var, data = pc, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : invalid type (list) for variable 'var'`

Comment: @dcarlson yeah! I don't want to look at environmental distance as a whole, but rather want the stepwise analysis to return significant predictor variables from within the environmental data which I can then use for further tests

Comment: You compute a distance between two sites as your dependent variable so there are n(n -1)/2 distances. Your independent variables are for a single site, not the distance between two sites. If you have 10 sites, there are 45 distances, but only 10 values for each independent variable. You need to rethink your analysis. Maybe canonical correlation analysis. Or use the independent variables to predict diversity of the site.